# Show/hide div on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, hide, show

I have a div element `#btns` that is hidden by default. It should be displayed on scrolling `200px` from top and again hidden after `500px` from top.

Here is my (non-working) code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>200) {
        $('#btns').fadeIn();
    } 
    elseif ($(this).scrollTop()<500) {
        $('#btns').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#btns').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: Please provide a [Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class hide in button like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log('scrolling ', $(window).scrollTop(), $(document).height());
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 200 && $(window).scrollTop() <= ($(document).height() - 500)) {
            $('#btns').removeClass('hide');
        } else {
            $('#btns').addClass('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/1ks8at6r/5/