# Hiding top header on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I know this question has been asked, but I am having a bug and I cannot find the mistake.

I have a top header above the navbar and when user scrolls down the height of the header (it is 50px) then I need to hide it. It works perfectly fine on my browser when I use the developer tools device toolbar, but after uploading to server I get a following bug: when I first scroll, the header is hidden, but when I scroll for the second time, it shows again and when I scroll for the third time, it disappears completely and it works. What could be the issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //hide the top logo
  var wdwWidth = $(window).width();
  if (wdwWidth <= 768) {
    $(".navbar").css("top", 50);
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('.navbar').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
      $(".navbar").css("top", "0px");
    } else {
      $(".navbar").css("top", "50px");
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() >= stickyHeaderTop) {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var navTop = 50 - scroll;
        if (navTop <= 0) {
          navTop = 0;
        }
        $(".navbar").css("top", navTop);
      } else {
        $(".navbar").css("top", "50px");
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(".navbar").css("top", "0px");
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 164px;
}



/*******************************
MENU AND HEADER
*******************************/

#header-top-logo {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(167, 85, 194, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 105%;
}

.super {
  font-family: Norican;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffea6a;
}

.hoidjad {
  font-family: LeagueSpartan;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffea6a;
}

.super.logo,
.hoidjad.logo {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  font-family: LeagueSpartan;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #ffea6a;
  color: #000 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.search-nanny {
  line-height: 7px !important;
  background-color: #ffea6a;
  width: 175px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.search-nanny>a:hover,
.search-nanny>a:focus {
  background-color: #ffea6a;
  height: 40px;
}

.nav.navbar-item>li>a.nav-link,
.nav.navbar-item>li>a.nav-link {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.primary.navbar.navbar-item,
.primary.navbar>.navbar-item {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #ffea6a;
  width: 175px;
  height: 42px;
}

.nav.navbar-item>li>a.search-nanny,
.nav.navbar-item>li>a.search-nanny {
  background-color: #ffea6a;
  padding-left: 40px;
}


/* OVERWRITE NAVBAR SO IT WONT COLLAPSE*/

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li,
.navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right!important;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease-out, padding 0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease-out, padding 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-out, padding 0s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(154, 154, 154, 0.5) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(154, 154, 154, 0.5) !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(154, 154, 154, 0.5) !important;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  box-shadow: none;
  min-height: 56px;
}

.index-header-right-row {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/************************
FOOTER
************************/

.social-media-icons {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  right: 94px;
}

.footer-text {
  font-family: LeagueSpartan;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 57px 0 28px 0;
}

.footer-text-paragraph {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #dbc5da;
}

.company-name {
  color: #ffea6a;
}

.footer-area {
  background: #af66c8;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 164px;
  z-index: 999;
}


/*******************************
responsive section starts
*******************************/

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .index-header-right-row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .nav.navbar-item>li>a.search-nanny,
  .nav.navbar-item>li>a.search-nanny {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  .content-area {
    margin-top: 6.5rem;
  }
  .social-media-icons {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .footer-text {
    padding: 115px 0 35px 0;
  }
  .footer-area {
    height: 230px;
  }
  .collapse.navbar-collapse {
    height: 56px;
  }
  .search-nanny {
    width: 120px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #9113bb;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none !important;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .collapse.navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #header-top-logo {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-btn {
    width: 115px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1824px) {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" id="header-top-logo">
  <p><a href="/"><span class="super">super</span> <span class="hoidjad">hoidjad</span></a></p></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top primary navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-item">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Meist</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Artiklid</a></li>
          <li class="nav-btn"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#searchNannyModel" class="search-nanny">Otsi hoidjat</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You aren't calling document ready but are using some jQuery; are you running jQuery on your page?

Comment: Please correct the snippet I made for you by removing the template stuff and replace it with actual HTML and CSS

Comment: @NathanielFlick I am calling document ready

Comment: Not in your example... @raqulka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's a great answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552135/show-hide-div-on-window-scroll).

Basically add a hide class on scroll rather than trying to control the show hide in nested if/else statements.

Here's the code it uses:

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log('scrolling ', $(window).scrollTop(), $(document).height());
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 200 && $(window).scrollTop() <= ($(document).height() - 500)) {
        $('#btns').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#btns').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

});

[The fiddle for the example here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ks8at6r/5/).

The function watches scroll position and then adds a class to the button in this case to hide it. You want to use this jQuery and reverse the order so it hides on scroll rather than the other way around.

I think the repetition bug you are seeing is also due to your nested if/else statements.

**EDIT: See updated CodePen here that works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZzoKb**

Instead of using classes I simply used jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut methods on the nav element. Rearrange the code as you see fit.

Comment: this removes the little fade effect

Comment: As I said in the question, my solution works fine in the browser but it gets bugged on mobile.

Comment: Ok all good - use fadeIn and fadeOut on the nav element and not a class on nav.

Comment: Will try now! Let's see what happens

Comment: Ok, now I've done two things to finally answer your question: 1. Made the fade a function that I can call anytime 2. wired that "fadeFunction" to a window resize event that fires anytime the window viewport changes and set it to 768px viewport, but this is pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137935/discussion-between-nathaniel-flick-and-raqulka).

Answer (score -1):

Why do not do a condicional when scrollTop >= 50 $(.navbar).hide  and when <= 50px scrollTop $.(.navbar).show, is code much short and free bugs